# How to get hardware print?

Tags: hardware, visual-studio-express

Can someone tell me how to get the hardware print of my computer, on VB 2010 express, or where and how is that stored? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to figure out what hardware is attached to your computer is to use [WMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) to get the information. Microsoft has created a tool that will create C#, VB.Net and VBScript sample code which you can run with the program and see what the values are, you can then add it to your program. This tool is called the [`WMI Code Creator`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572). I would start out by exploring the Classes starting with `Win32_`

---

Now that I know what you are trying to do I can be a little more specific. The WMI NameSpace you are needing is `root\CIMV2` the Class is `Win32_DiskDrive` or `Win32_PhysicalMedia` and the Property is `SerialNumber`. I made a small console test app in Vb.net. It will print out the drive serialnumbers on your PC, if you need  it in c# I can modify. There are also numerous other [SO Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hard%20drive%20serial%20number) about the same subject.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Management

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        For Each sn As String In GetDriveSerialNumber()
            Console.WriteLine(sn.Trim)
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Function GetDriveSerialNumber() As List(Of String)
        Dim snList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        Try
            Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive")

            For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
                snList.Add(queryObj("SerialNumber").ToString())
            Next
        Catch err As ManagementException
            Throw
        End Try
        Return snList
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: is it DriverCompleteRequest ? im kind of lost idk how to code this part to return the hardware id <_<

Comment: @WeskerPower what device are you looking for the hardware id on

Comment: volume serial number of hdrive, well i guess that any serial number that dosnt change to be able to give access to that user, to my data base, thats basicly what i want to do, i have seen some programs that call that Hardware-Print should be 8 numbers 4-4 or just the 8 numbers, but im brand new in this WMI and it has alot of addreses or guides and since i dont know what im exactly looking for it is a mess for me, i appreciatte if you explain me where i can find that in WMI and how to code it, i think it is usefull for any1 looking for this info :)

Comment: i think that my biggest issue at the moment is that i dont understand how wmi works, i tried to test it, it returns values like 26,4,1,2 but nothing that im searching for, or im probably doing it wrong...

Comment: @weskerpower I am traveling at the moment will get back to you in 3 to 4 hrs

Comment: i can wait no problem :), have a nice trip :)

Comment: @WeskerPower I added some code and some additional links, let me know if it helps

Comment: thanks alot that pretty much solve my problem it was a revision that i needed

Comment: @WeskerPower Glad to be of help

Comment: 1 sec did you do it in visual studio 2010 express somehow i found what i wanted but everything coming from WIM gives me errors am i missing some imports ?

'WMI - root\CIMV2 - Win32_DiskDrive - FirmwareRevision

Comment: Imports System
Imports System.Management

Module Module1

    Private _queryObj As Object

    Private Property queryObj(ByVal p1 As String) As Object
        Get
            Return _queryObj
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Object)
            _queryObj = value
        End Set
    End Property

even with the _query is not working LOL, im so bad at this

Comment: @WeskerPower right click on the project, select add reference then select System.Management from the .Net Tab

Comment: that worked mmm i shouldnt bother you any further but how can i call that module to give me x value As String ?

Comment: @WeskerPower did you look at my example?, I am just setting `queryObj("SerialNumber").ToString()`.  Change the return type of your Function from Object to String and then change your `Return _queryObj` to `Return _queryObj.ToString()`

Comment: i did see it, im sorry if im been stupid but, until now i didnt worked with modules, just multiple forms and im getting into it http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmZWIJHAfg8 im using your code and just changed it to "Win32_DiskDrive" still got no idea until no on how to tall that value into a label in form1, but i asume ill get there, but i hope you enlight me again :)

Comment: @WeskerPower I used a module just to create a quick standalone demo program, I used a function so you could import it into your program. I also used a list because a computer can have more than one drive. So what you need to do is check the list to make sure it isn't null and then do something like this.  `Dim mylist As List(Of String) = GetDriveSerialNumber()
        If mylist.Count > 0 Then
            label.Text = mylist.Item(0)
        End If`

Comment: xP i made it, sorry if i gave you a hardtime, dislexia + a lack of grammar + new things made problems all the way, the string was empy and now it works, well today i learn something new and for that thank you even more